# Inserting into Table 'User' with Dapper.Rainbow

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-rainbow

I am using Dapper.Rainbow and have come across an issue when inserting into a table named 'User'.

I can get other tables to work perfectly, but when try to insert to the `Users` table it will fail.

I have used the Sql Query inspector to determine that the generated query does not have any `[ ]` around the table name. Once I recraft the query with square brackets, it works fine.

When I use `Table<User>(this, "[Users]");` it will set the private property `likelyTableName` to the correct value (`[User]`).

However as soon as `database.Init(dbconn,3);` it will change the `likelyTableName` string back to `User`.

I have been checking out the Dapper-dot-net Github project and looked through the database.cs source for dapper.rainbow, but am at a loss as parts of it are in IL.

Is there a way to get dapper.rainbow to work with a table named `User`??

Answer (score 1):

It is really a bad idea to use reserved words for table (or field, view etc) names. I think that is likely causing you problems. Better to bite the bullet once and change the name, than fight with it forever.

For reference, here are a list of reserved words (to avoid):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Comment: I do agree with your point, however having looked through the Rainbow code a bit more, I feel like there may be a bug in their code. Some of the Senior Devs at my work are saying that using square brackets is a good practise. And it looks as if Rainbow will never put square brackets around your table name if the table already exists in your DB.